# How to set floating label text colour of edittext when it is not on focus different from edittext hint colour?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, styles, android-textinputlayout

How to set floating label text colour of edittext when it is not on focus different from edittext hint colour?

I have set hint colour as grey initially.When user focusses on edittext it changes to red.The issue is when focus of edittext is removed after typing some text then floating label text colour of edittext changes to grey.I want it to remain red only.Grey should be hint colour only when no text is written in edittext and floating label colour should be red always even when edittext is not in focus.

Below is code i am using-

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/amountLayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.App.TextInputLayout"
                        android:paddingTop="@dimen/dp1">

                        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:hint="@string/amount"
                            android:textColor="@color/red"
                            android:inputType="number"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<style name="TextAppearance.App.TextInputLayout" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/sp8</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
     <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/red</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/red</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/red</item>
     <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/grey</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I also have this problem, but I solved it, this is my solution that may help you.

Add below **only in your TextInputLayout**, not in TextInputEditText.

```
android:textColorHint="@color/yourLabelColorWhenNotFocus"
```

If you set this attribute in both TextInputEditText and TextInputLayout, or just in TextInputEditText, it won't work well.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a way to do this, and from reading the source of `TextInputLayout`, it turns out this is not possible programmatically **because there is no way to modify the private member `mDefaultTextColor`**, which is what the TextInputLayout changes the hint color to when the view is unfocused. The only way to set this is via xml:

```
android:textColorHint="@color/red"
```

which obviously isn't enough because we want to be able to set this dynamically.

**So I wrote accessors for it**, via a pair of extension functions.

```
/**
 * We need these accessors because this field is private and programmatically unstyleable,
 * and we want to change the default (both focused and unfocused) hint text color.
 *
 * This is made safe by simply defaulting to null at any point there could be a problem.
 */
private fun TextInputLayout.getDefaultTextColor(): ColorStateList? {
    javaClass.getDeclaredField("mDefaultTextColor").let { field ->
        field.isAccessible = true
        return field.get(this) as? ColorStateList?
    }
}

private fun TextInputLayout.setDefaultTextColor(color: ColorStateList) {
    javaClass.getDeclaredField("mDefaultTextColor").let { field ->
        field.isAccessible = true
        field.set(this, color)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
//Get the original color
normalTextColor = text_input_layout.getDefaultTextColor()

//Change the color to another color
text_input_layout.setDefaultTextColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(context, R.color.red))
text_input_layout.setHintTextAppearance(R.style.TextAppearance_Error)

//Change the color back to the default 
//(the TextInputLayout likes to use the inner TextInputEditText's hint color state list as a fallback, so we will too)
text_input_layout.setDefaultTextColor(normalTextColor ?: inner_text.hintTextColors)
text_input_layout.setHintTextAppearance(R.style.TextAppearance_Design_Hint)
```

You'll notice the above references a `TextAppearance_Error` style, its definition is simply:

```
<style name="TextAppearance.Error" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Hint">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change the color of the floating hint just by inserting this attribute inside editText

```
android:textColorHighlight="@android:color/white"
```

or if you want to change the color in editText(not the floating one) you can add this in your theme

```
 <item name="android:textColorHint">@android:color/white</item>
```

Comment: The issue is that when edittext is not on focus the foating label text colour of edittext changes  to the hint colour..so whatever colour i have specified in android:textColorHint ,floating label colour will change to that once edittext is not in focus